# Can I enter Switzerland with a German temporary residence permit?

Tags: switzerland, german-residents

I have a temporary residence permit (fiktionsbescheinigung), valid for the next six months, which I got in Germany under § 81 Section 4 of the Residence Act. Can I travel to Switzerland with this certificate (bescheinigung)?

Comment: Is the question can you travel with this document instead of a passport or along side a passport?

Comment: @Jacob  i will be carrying the  passport , but the question is With this document (fiktionbescheinigung) can i travel to switzerland ?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on your Fiktionsbescheinigung as described in german on [this official document](https://www.sem.admin.ch/dam/data/sem/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/vhb/vhb1-anh02-d.pdf)

You have three boxes, which can be ticked on page three.

If the first or second are ticked you are not allowed to enter Switzerland without a visa

If the third one is ticked, you may enter switzerland with an official expired "Aufenthaltsbewilligung" or a Visa.

**So long story short:** You probably need a Passport with a valid visa inside.

Comment: Looking at the [image from wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Fiktionsbescheinigung-Beispiel.jpg), looks like third box is checked only for cases issued under `§ 81 Section 4`.

Comment: Since the source you link to is in German, most users of this site will be unable to read it.  Can you explain what each of the three boxes represents?