# Travelling with Fiktionsbescheinigung

Tags: schengen, germany, german-residents, student-visas

I have a student visa under renewal and the German Kreisverwaltungsreferat has given a Fiktionsbescheinigung (temporary residence permit). Is it allowed to travel to other European countries with the Fiktionsbescheinigung ? Due to corona pandemic the card is taking too long to arrive.

Comment: see answer https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/159187/95267

Comment: Or this one https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124607/can-i-enter-switzerland-with-a-german-temporary-residence-permit